# Extract string column in multiple columns

Tags: pandas, slice, extract

I have the next df:

```
Match                       Count
Asren_Blue_Coached           879
Asren_Blue_NotCoached        721
Asren_RED_Coached            6567
Asren_RED_NotCoached         764
Asren_White_Coached          762
Asren_White_NotCoached       431
Asren_Yellow_Coached         375
Asren_Yellow_NotCoached      412
Hrew_Blue_Coached            689
Hrew_Blue_NotCoached         634
...
```

I want to add three new columns,

One column for each word before the underscore in column 'Match'

So, the expected output looks like this:

```
Match                       NewCol1   NewCol2    NewCol3      Count    
Asren_Blue_Coached           Asren      Blue     Coached       879      
Asren_Blue_NotCoached        Asren      Blue     NotCoached    721
Asren_RED_Coached            Asren      RED      Coached       6567
Asren_RED_NotCoached         Asren      RED      NotCoached    764
Asren_White_Coached          Asren      White    Coached       762
Asren_White_NotCoached       Asren      White    NotCoached    431
Asren_Yellow_Coached         Asren      Yellow   Coached       375
Asren_Yellow_NotCoached      Asren      Yellow   NotCoached    412
Hrew_Blue_Coached            Hrew       Blue     Coached       689
Hrew_Blue_NotCoached         Hrew       Blue     NotCoached    634
...
```

Do you know how can I do it?

I'm working with pandas in Jupyter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split`, and assign the return to 3 columns named are you wish, and specify the `delimiter` to be "_"

See below:

```
df[['NewCol1', 'NewCol2','NewCol3']] = df['Match'].str.split('_', expand=True)
```

which prints your desired output:

```
print(df)
                     Match  Count NewCol1 NewCol2     NewCol3
0       Asren_Blue_Coached    879   Asren    Blue     Coached
1    Asren_Blue_NotCoached    721   Asren    Blue  NotCoached
2        Asren_RED_Coached   6567   Asren     RED     Coached
3     Asren_RED_NotCoached    764   Asren     RED  NotCoached
4      Asren_White_Coached    762   Asren   White     Coached
5   Asren_White_NotCoached    431   Asren   White  NotCoached
6     Asren_Yellow_Coached    375   Asren  Yellow     Coached
7  Asren_Yellow_NotCoached    412   Asren  Yellow  NotCoached
8        Hrew_Blue_Coached    689    Hrew    Blue     Coached
9     Hrew_Blue_NotCoached    634    Hrew    Blue  NotCoached
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split a column on a delimiter. Then just mark `expand=True` to get new columns instead of a list.

```
df["Match"].str.split("_", expand=True)
```